# Remove _id from output and nested element in Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

With my .findOne function I'm getting response:

```
{
    "_id": "59955bb0cd522a00bcaab08c",
    "lang": "en",
    "__v": 0,
    "message_subsets": [
        {
            "identifier": "errors",
            "_id": "59955bb0cd522a00bcaab08d",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "identifier": "invalid",
                    "message_text": "$FIELD$ is invalid",
                    "_id": "59955bb0cd522a00bcaab091"
                },
                {
                    "identifier": "empty",
                    "message_text": "$FIELD$ is required",
                    "_id": "59955bb0cd522a00bcaab090"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to exclude _id from output and its nested elements with some .findOne query parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think mongo always returns the ID in a find query, you could try:

`Query.findOne({_id: queryId}).select("-_id")`

I haven't tested this, and am not sure if this will work. But worth the try ;-)

Comment: Yeap, using `.findOne({}).select("-_id -message_subsets._id -message_subsets.messages._id")` everything works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the collection is Test

```
db.test.findOne({},{_id:0,"message_subsets.messages._id":0, "message_subsets._id":0 })
```

Comment: That can be used too.